# Problem with BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE_FRACTION

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I'm using the Boost::Test library, and I am trying to check if an actual percent value is close to the expected value:

```
BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE_FRACTION(
    items[i].ExpectedPercent,
    items[i].ActualCount / totalCount,
    0.05);
```

For some reason this check fails even when the values are close enough:

```
difference between items[i].ExpectedPercent{0.40000000000000002}
   and items[i].ActualCount / totalReturned{0.42999999999999999}
                                    exceeds 0.050000000000000003
```

Is this a problem with Boost or a problem with how I am using Boost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some testing, it turns out that the documentation for BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE_FRACTION is incorrect. The tolerance should be specified as a fraction of the expected value.

So, TFAE:

```
BOOST_CHECK(abs(x - y) < (min(x, y) * 0.1));
BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(x, y, 10);
BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE_FRACTION(x, y, 0.1);
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to check if there is a related report in Boost Trac and if not, report it there or send your comment to Boost mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem with how you are using boost.

The last argument is a percent tolerance, not an absolute variance value.  5% of 0.4 is 0.02.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE and BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE_FRACTION won't work if you check if something is near 0. Then you can use:

```
BOOST_CHECK(abs(x - y) < accurancy);
```